# Assigning transactions to projects in Ledger?

Tags: accounting

I find I really want to add an additional, orthogonal layer to the account hierarchy. Quicken and Quickbooks lets you do this, but I'm not sure what the best way is in Ledger. I wish I could do something like this:

```
2018-08-28 Home Depot
    Expenses:Raw Materials/Client A:Phase 1     $42.87
    Expenses:Raw Materials/Client B:Phase 2     $37.50
    Liabilities:Credit Card:Chase

2018-08-28 Western Tool & Supply
    Expenses:Tooling/Client A                   $53.01
    Liabilities:Credit Card:Chase
```

And you could constrain queries like this (perhaps with a command line option to distinguish projects and accounts with the same name):

```
$ ledger "Client A"
    $ 95.88     Expenses
    $ 42.87       Raw Materials
    $ 53.01       Tooling
-----------

$ ledger "Client B"
    $ 37.50     Expenses:Raw Materials
-----------
    $ 37.50
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a corporate HD card.  Enable POs for all purchases through card holder services (I used the pro desk).  If this is that important to you, I would just make 2 different purchases and use 2 different POs.  When it comes on your bill, you can classify them accordingly to their purpose.  Most HDs won't care and in fact understand you have account standards.  I use Wave apps personally.  It isn't as flexible as QB, but is free and works.